# How do I locate the button element and click it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<button class="sfc-value sfc-js-change sfc-js-field sfc-ui-btn fo-ui-btn fo-ui-container fo-ui-fixed style-114 layout-156 sfc-js-click" type="button">
    <span class="sfc-caption fo-ui-label style-115 layout-157 fo-ui-no-icon">Next</span>
</button>
```

I am new to selenium and I am confused with the classes to target in here. So any best way to target the element .I need to click the button here.

Answer (score 2):

You create an xpath that starts with the span using the text contained, then refer -back- to the button itself:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']/..")).click();
```

**edited

Comment: tried this and got this error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Next']/button"}

Comment: You might need to show more of your HTML.  Perhaps the span is inside an IFRAME.  If you are using Chrome, press F12 and then right-click on the element and select "inspect element"  Then in the HTML code highlighted, right click on the highlight section and select copy xpath.  See what it says.

Comment: Actually the F12 part is not necessary - right click inspect will open the tools.

Comment: I had my xpath backwards - the button is the parent, not the child.  I've made the adjustment to the xpath, but I'm not 100% certain that it's the correct syntax.  I don't often need to refer to the parent node, so I don't recall the exact syntax from memory, but I'm fairly certain ".." refers to parent node as a shortcut.

Comment: Another way to do it is `//button[.//span[.='Next']]`. I've tested this and it works. Yours also works.

Comment: Or even shorter `//button[span='Next']`

Comment: @Andersson I was not aware of that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To desired element is a dynamic element so to target the element and click it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following (**Java**) solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.sfc-value.sfc-js-change.sfc-js-field.sfc-ui-btn.fo-ui-btn.fo-ui-container.fo-ui-fixed.style-114.layout-156.sfc-js-click>span.sfc-caption.fo-ui-label.style-115.layout-157.fo-ui-no-icon"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='sfc-value sfc-js-change sfc-js-field sfc-ui-btn fo-ui-btn fo-ui-container fo-ui-fixed style-114 layout-156 sfc-js-click']/span[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click();
  ```